# SQL query order by, not working for last 10 records in database

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

Hi I have a database table: VQ_log with the following structure:

Column 1: Page; Column 2: event; Column 3:msg; Column 4:event_datetime

I run this following query:

```
SELECT page,event,msg,event_datetime
FROM VQ_log  
    WHERE event_datetime >= :dateStart AND event_datetime <= :dateEnd
        AND msg = :merchantID
            ORDER BY event;"
```

The first 100 records are sorted in order by event(which is a numeric number), however, the last 10 records have a numeric record smaller than the first 100 records
Please advise

Comment: What data type does column 'event' have?

Comment: Can you list your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
SELECT * FROM VQ_log  
    WHERE event_datetime between dateStart AND dateEnd
        AND msg = :merchantID ORDER BY event desc;
```

BTW, from where does `dateStart`,`dateEnd` and `merchantID` values are coming? doesn't looks like this is your entire query.

**EDIT:**

Not sure what your table structure/schema is but per my understanding your `event` column is `varchar` type rather than a `int` type (considering you are using MYSQL) and hence you are not getting the proper order.

For example I tried this:

```
create table mytab (page varchar(10), event varchar(10), msg varchar(20), 
event_datetime datetime);

insert into mytab values('page1',772,'Hi',curdate());

insert into mytab values('page21',700,'Hello',curdate());

insert into mytab values('page3',3422,'Go',curdate());

insert into mytab values('page31',3000,'There',curdate());
```

Then when I run the below query

```
SELECT * FROM mytab  
    WHERE event_datetime between curdate() AND '2013-07-29'
         ORDER BY event;
```

This is what the result is (See the event column):

```
PAGE    EVENT   MSG     EVENT_DATETIME
page31  3000    There   July, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000
page3   3422    Go  July, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000
page21  700     Hello   July, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000
page1   772     Hi  July, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

But if I change the `event` column to `int` as

```
create table mytab (page varchar(10), event int, msg varchar(20), 
event_datetime datetime);
```

Then result becomes

```
PAGE    EVENT   MSG     EVENT_DATETIME
page21  700     Hello   July, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000
page1   772     Hi  July, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000
page31  3000    There   July, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000
page3   3422    Go  July, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi I ran the following query, but there is still this set of records that don't follow the SQL query
For instance:
event:
772
.
.
.
700.
3422..
.
.
3000
There is always this set of records where the event value range from
772 to 700 that don't follow the SQL query